# Laravel mix npm run dev on linux produce SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, laravel-mix

I can't use npm run dev|prod|watch on my staging linux server. It produces this :

```
 npm run production

glob error [Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/root/.npm/_logs'] {
  errno: -13,
  code: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'scandir',
  path: '/root/.npm/_logs'
}

> production
> mix --production

/var/www/html/preprodCerf2021/node_modules/laravel-mix/bin/cli.js:2
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
          ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1065:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

nodeJs is up to date v 16.8.0 and npm v 7.21.0 my the compilation works perfectly on my windows dev machine.

This is the files ownership :

```
-rwxr-xr-x   1 www-data www-data    817 sept. 30 10:06 package.json
-rw-r--r--   1 www-data www-data 820729 sept. 30 10:32 package-lock.json
-rwxr-xr-x   1 www-data www-data   1202 janv. 22  2021 phpunit.xml
drwxr-xr-x   8 www-data www-data   4096 sept.  8 16:02 public
-rwxr-xr-x   1 www-data www-data   3780 janv. 22  2021 README.md
drwxr-xr-x   8 www-data www-data   4096 août  31 12:55 resources
drwxr-xr-x   2 www-data www-data   4096 janv. 28  2021 routes
-rwxr-xr-x   1 www-data www-data    563 janv. 22  2021 server.php
drwxrwxr-x   6 www-data www-data   4096 mars   5  2021 storage
-rwxr-xr-x   1 www-data www-data    181 janv. 22  2021 .styleci.yml
-rwxr-xr-x   1 www-data www-data    548 sept.  9 15:36 tailwind.config.js
drwxr-xr-x   4 www-data www-data   4096 janv. 28  2021 tests
drwxr-xr-x  61 www-data www-data   4096 août  31 12:56 vendor
-rwxr-xr-x   1 www-data www-data    669 sept. 30 11:58 webpack.mix.js
```

Comment: Are you running this as sudo/root user? And the node/npm versions you've mentioned are for the root user? Can you also share the file ownership user:group for the files in your project?

Comment: I'm running npm as root, files are owned by www-data:www-data

Answer (score 1):

In the end I tried this succesfully, npm is very mysterious

```
rm node_modules -rf && npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

I've faced similar issues where I was trying to run npm as root user but the file ownership was with different users. You can try one of the following ways:

1. Try running `npm` with the www-data user
2. Change ownership of the files to a sudoable user

   ```
   # login as a user that has sudo access and change file ownership
   sudo chown -R myuser:myuser /path/to/project/

   # run npm commands as myuser
   npm install && npm run production

   # change the permissions to previous state
   sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/project/
   ```
3. Change ownership of the files to the root user (this hasn't worked for me so far but may work for you)

   ```
   # enter sudo mode and change ownership to root
   sudo su
   chown -R root:root /path/to/project/

   # run npm commands as root user
   npm install && npm run production

   # change the permissions to previous state
   chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/project/

   # exit sudo mode
   exit
   ```

Comment: Running as www-data produce "This account is currently not available."

Comment: Did you try the other two options? Try with a different user (which has sudo access or try with the sudo user).

Comment: I was already using root user and as www-data it says the account is unavailable

Comment: Yes, www-data isn't a shell user so you won't be able to use it. Please check my answer above. If you're trying with root, change the files and directory ownerships to root user and then try running npm.